# Mysql update if condition of subquery how to

Tags: mysql, sql

Suppose I have 2 tables

---

**Table 1: users**

Attributes: id (int), expires_at (varchar), status (enum)

*expires_at* could be a DATETIME, or it could be a number (the number of logins the person can perform).

*status* can be "active", "expiring", "expired", etc..

---

**Table 2: staff**

Attributes: id (int), user_id (int), contract (enum)

*contract* can be either: "chronologically" or "fixed number of times"

If "chronologically", *users*'s expires_at will have a DATETIME value.

If "fixed number of times", *users*'s expires_at will have a number value as VARCHAR.

---

One approach could be to create a scheduled event on MySQL so that, every day, at 11:59am, MySQL will check **expires_at** and set **status** as expiring or expired.

I'm looking for something like:

```
UPDATE users SET status = CASE (SELECT expires_at FROM users WHERE status = "active" AND id IN (SELECT id FROM staff WHERE contract = "fixed number of times")
    WHEN expires_at < 10 AND expires_at > 0 THEN "expiring"
    WHEN expires_at <= 0 THEN "expired"
END
```

for "fixed number of times" contract, and another similar query for "chronologically". Problem is: the above query's syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe u should use

```
SELECT user_id FROM staff
```

not

```
SELECT id FROM staff
```

try

```
UPDATE users 
    SET 
        status = 
            CASE
                WHEN expires_at < 10 AND expires_at > 0 THEN 'expiring'
                WHEN expires_at <= 0 THEN 'expired'
                ELSE status
            END
    WHERE 
        id IN (SELECT user_id FROM staff WHERE contract = "fixed number of times")
        AND status = 'active'
```

Comment: Wow, thank you! I was trying to put the condition after CASE, whereas I should have put WHERE (contidion). I feel really noob right now